# Send a form to the email, using Android App

Tags: android, email, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a blog app in where a user will have to complete a form, to apply for an event. After completing this form and clicking the submit button, the filled will be sent to the event poster. My question is, how can I send this form to the event poster, using firebase.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tied so far?

Comment: I am created almost the role app, register with email verification, post images, create events, added calendar, but I am struggling with is when an job/event is available and a candidate wants to apply for it, a form page is being displayed and after filling the form, the same will be sent to the event/job poster. I am quite lost on this. I would appreciate any help.